# Start Animations When Revolution Slider Scrolls Into View

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, slider

I need to use Slider Revolution to animate content when the slider is scrolled into view. I already have working solution - http://www.themepunch.com/faq/start-animations-when-slider-scrolls-into-view/ but it has one serious bug.

When user already seen slider it start to animate again when user scrolling it again.

I want to make slide not to re-animate when user scroll to it after he already seen it.

Clarification: user scrolls down to slide - slide start to animate - (super!) - user go down to the end of the page - then go back - and slider start to animate from the beginning (bad (for me)). I want to make slider stop after he played the animation for first time.

Update with relevant code:

```
var win, slider, sliderHeight, sliderPaused = true, winHeight,

// Change the "revapi6" part here to whatever "revapi" name that your slider uses
slider = revapi6.on('revolution.slide.onloaded', function() {

    win = jQuery(window).on('scroll', checkScroll).on('resize', sizer);
    sizer();

});

function sizer() {

    sliderHeight = slider.height();
    winHeight = win.height();
    checkScroll();

}

function checkScroll() {

    var scrTop = win.scrollTop(),
    offset = slider.offset().top;

    if(offset <= scrTop + winHeight && offset + sliderHeight >= scrTop) {

        if(sliderPaused) slider.revshowslide(2);
        sliderPaused = false;

    }
    else {

        if(!sliderPaused) slider.revshowslide(1);
        sliderPaused = true;

    }

}
```

It's in "Custom JavaScript" block in my slider settings. All just like here - http://www.themepunch.com/faq/start-animations-when-slider-scrolls-into-view/.
Site - uhhu.net

Comment: Can you please update with your relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Resolve. Maybe it's not the best way, but it works and i don't know better

Comment this part

```
    /*else {

        if(!sliderPaused) slider.revshowslide(1);
        sliderPaused = true;

    }*/
```

Answer (score 0):

**I let you here my solution:**

**1- Go to Slider Revolution:**

[image]

**2- Select your slider:**

[image]

**3- Click on Slider Settings Tab:**

[image]

**4- In the right panel click on "Parallax and 3D" and compare with your current configuration:**

[image]

**5- In the right panel click on "Scroll Effects"(bellow of "Parallax and 3D")  and compare with your current configuration:**

[image]

**6- To finish Save the configurations:**

[image]